# How do I resolve 'Argument types do not match parameters' in TypeScript with React Navigation?

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I try to use Typescript in ReactNavigation, and got error by IDE (webstorm)

My `Navigator`:

```
export type RootStackParamList = {
    AppStack: undefined;
    AuthStack: undefined;
};

const RootStack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();

const Navigation: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
    return (
        <RootStack.Navigator>
            <RootStack.Screen name="AuthStack" component={AuthStack} />
            <RootStack.Screen name="AppStack" component={AppStack} />
        </RootStack.Navigator>
    );
}
```

My `LoginScreen` in `AuthStack`:

```
type NavigationProps = StackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList>;
const LoginScreen = () => {
    const navigation = useNavigation<StackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList>>();
    const requestLogin = () => {
        navigation.navigate('AppStack');  // IDE show error in 'AppStack'
    }
}
```

I run app and everything ok, but the IDE still show error: `Argument types do not match parameters`.
It isn't an eslint error.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: It seems Your IDE cannot detect type or variable is just treated as any type (so on running app, looks like no error).

First, try same code on VSCode. In general typescript is good linked wiht VSCode.
Second, try specify type as any without generics. If it is works, maybe Webstorm has bug

Comment: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/9741 This has been an issue there are few solutions mentioned here which you can use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it's a bug of old version of Webstorm. I just update Webstorm to 2023.2.5 and the error disappear